# MS Bot how to forward Luis Entities to child Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to forward the `Entities` from the `LuisResults` to a child dialog class.  Can anyone assist on how to go about this?

**Luis Dialog Class**

```
...
[LuisIntent("Foo")]
public async Task Foo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    var entities = result.Entities;
    await context.Forward(new FooDialog(), AfterFooDialog, entities, 
    CancellationToken.None);
}
...
```

**FooDialog Class**

```
...
public async StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}

private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, List<string> entities, IAwaitable(IMessageActivity) result)
{
    var _entites = await entities;
    ...

}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to do this is that, you initialize the entities in the `FooDialog` via constructor. So pass the entities to `FooDialog` in the constructor while forwarding it from `LuisDialog`.

So your code would be :

**Luis Dialog**

```
[LuisIntent("Foo")]
    public async Task Foo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var entities = result.Entities;
        await context.Forward(new FooDialog(entities), AfterFooDialog, entities, CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

And your **FooDialog**

```
[Serializable]
public class FooDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public IList<EntityRecommendation> _entities { get; set; }

    public FooDialog(IList<EntityRecommendation> entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
    }

    public FooDialog()
    {}

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result )
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Entity : " + _entities.First().Entity);
    }

}
```

So now you have the entities inside the FooDialog class and accessible by any function within the object.

Comment: Thank you @Ashwin, that worked well.  Note I did not need the blank `public FooDialog() { }`

Comment: The reason for adding that constructor was that in later stages in case you want to call `FooDialog` without entities, it would be possible. So its upto the way you want to design it.

Comment: Hello Ashwin, I have did the same but in MessageReceivedAsync i have written PromptDialog.Confirm and on its resume handler i am extracting luis entities but after PromptDialog.Confirm i get this._entities as null..